# How to calculate least common multiple (LCM) for two numbers with constants (shifts)?

Tags: algorithms

What's the most effective algorithm to calculate LCM for 2 numbers where each of them has their own "shift"?

Example:

We want to find LCM for 25 + 5 as c and 30 + 10 as c
Then for the first case, the sequence will look like this:

25*1+5, 25*2+5, 25*3+5, 25*4+5...

And the second one:

30*1+10, 30*2+10, 30*3+10, 30*4+10...

In this case, the result should be 130 - 5th member of the first sequence and 4th of the second one.

Comment: In other words, given (positive?) $a,b,c,d$, you want to find the $n,m$ such that $an+b = cm+d$, with $an+b$ minimal.

Comment: This isn't always possible – for example, $2n+1 \neq 2m+2$ for all integer $n,m$.

Comment: When $d-c=1$ you are essentially looking for the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I thought.

Comment: Now, let's say I found the value 130 (as show in the example) using a cycle and going to the worst case value ((a+b)*(d+c)?) and I want it to be higher than x (eg. 1000). 
With a "classic" LCM, once LCM is found, this is fairly easy. Is there a way to do it the same with this?

Comment: If you are asking for all solutions of the equation, then yes, they are easy to find given a single solution. It's a nice exercise for you.

Comment: How is that possible? I've used this approach, which perfectly makes sense to me: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28848/least-common-multiple-of-a-and-b-greater-than-c

How could you add the shift to that?

Comment: You will need to modify it somewhat. If you understand what's behind the algorithm, I'm sure modifying it to suit your needs won't be too difficult.

Comment: I've tried adding the constatnts to the the end formula, multiplying it and such, but I still wasn't able to figure this one out. 
Anything more specific, please?

Comment: My answer gives a formula for *all* solutions. You can use this formula to find the minimal solution larger than some number. Try solving first the following easier question: what is the minimal multiple of A which is larger than B?

Comment: B-(B%A)+A, that's easy

Comment: It's not much different in your case.

Comment: The closest I got was B-(B%A)+A+c+d, which is definitely incorrect
When I already found 130 and want to find the multiple higher than 1000, with this formula I will get 1055, which matches the 25 + 5 sequence but misses the 30+10 one

Comment: I am sorry, but I just have no idea.

Comment: Sorry to hear. My answer shows that all solutions are of the form $B,A+B,2A+B,\ldots$ for appropriate $A,B$, where $B$ is the smallest solution and $A$ is the lcm of the two multiplicands. This reduces your task to the following: Given $M$, find the minimal number of the form $nA+B$ which is at least $M$. I'm confident that you can solve this on your own.

Comment: Thanks, that was the push I needed! 
In case someone else looks for an answer to this, it's M - ((M - B)%A)+A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given integers $a,b \geq 1$ and $c,d \geq 0$, you are looking for the set of solutions of $ax + c = by + d$ over integers $x,y \geq 0$. We can assume without loss of generality that $d = 0$ (replace $c,d$ with $c-d,0$ or $0,d-c$) and that $(a,b,c) = 1$ (otherwise, divide everything by the GCD).

I claim that if there is any solution then necessarily $(a,b) = 1$. Indeed, suppose that $(a,b) = g > 1$. If $ax + c = by$ then $g \mid ax,by$ implies $g \mid c$, and so $(a,b,c) = g > 1$, contrary to assumption. Therefore $(a,b) = 1$.

If $ax + c = by$ then $ax + c \equiv 0 \pmod{b}$ and so $x \equiv -c/a \pmod{b}$ (note that we can divide by $a$ since $(a,b)=1$). Similarly, $y \equiv c/b \pmod{a}$. These equations essentially give us both the minimal solution and all solutions.

As a demonstration, consider your example: $30x+10 = 25y+5$. This is equivalent to $6x+1 = 5y$, so $(a,b,c) = (6,5,1)$. Any solution must satisfy $x \equiv -1/6 \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$ and $y \equiv 1/5 \equiv 5 \pmod{6}$. Indeed, $6 \cdot 4 + 1 = 5 \cdot 5$. The general solution is $(x,y) = (4+5N,5+6N)$.

Comment: Could you please clarify, how did you get x and y (4 and 5)?
I thought, that the congruence you used should mean (-1/6)%5 = 4%5, but that's just not true. 
https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/congruence-modulo)

Comment: On the contrary, it is true. If you multiply $4$ by $6$ then you get $24=5\cdot 5-1$.

Comment: I know that in the end, it will make sense, but I don't understand, how do you get to these numbers. Maybe mod is something different than I think it is? https://imgur.com/a/NOFfx

Comment: I suggest reading some elementary number theory textbook, or reviewing any other resource on modular arithmetic.